# Iphone 4 stuck when trying to unlock with SIM PIN code

Tags: iphone, unlock, sim

The phone works normally except for the SIM. I can unlock it, then open apps, preferences etc. I've made a backup in iTunes, then reset the phone to factory settings, then restored the backup. This didn't fix the problem.

When I enter the SIM PIN code, the screen is fixed at "unlocking", while showing the number pad. I can't go back to the home screen. I can shut down the phone, restart it, everything is back to normal except for the SIM. I see that I still have three tries for the SIM. I've tried to enter a false PIN to see what happens, but then it's the same.

Is this a problem with the SIM or with the phone? Any ideas how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try by entering the unlock passcode instead of the SIM PIN?

Comment: Both codes are the same, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I'd ask your service provider. The SIM may be  broken, incompatible, too old or too new - the firmware in SIMs does change over the years.